# Css problem in IE. Jquery image / swf swap

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, debugging, flash

I have the following code:

```
                <html>
                <head>
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script> 
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/jquery.swfobject.1-1-1.min.js"></script>
                <style>
                div#test{background:#ffffff;width:360px;height:360px;display:none;z-index:5;position: fixed;}
                #mainimage{z-index:-1;}
                </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td><div id="test"></div>
                            <div id="mainimage"><img id="full_image" src="1.jpg" alt="0" width="360" height="360" border="0" /></div>
                            <span id="flash" style="width:360px;height:360px;border:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;z-index:-1;">
                            <object data="fireworks.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="flash_99458582" width="360" height="360">
                                <param name="movie" value="fireworks.swf"><param name="wmode" value="opaque">
                            </object>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="1.jpg" class="thumbnail"><img src="1.jpg" width="70" height="70"></a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="2.jpg" class="thumbnail"><img src="2.jpg" width="70" height="70"></a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="3.jpg" width="70" height="70" class="video"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>    
                <br /><br />
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#flash").hide();
                    $('a.thumbnail').click(function(){  
                    var src = $(this).attr('href');

                    $("#test").fadeIn("slow", function () {
                        //$("#test").fadeOut("slow");
                        $("#flash").hide();
                        $("#test").hide();
                        $("img#full_image").show();
                        $("img#full_image").css({ opacity: 0 });
                        //alert(src);
                        if (src != $('img#full_image').attr('src').replace(/\?(.*)/,'')){
                            $('img#full_image').attr('src', src+'?'+Math.floor(Math.random()*(10*100)));                
                        }

                        $('img#full_image').stop().animate({opacity: '1'}, 'slow');
                    });



                    //alert("here");
                    return false;
                    });     
                    $('img.video').click(function(){
                        $("img#full_image").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                            $("#test").show();
                            $("#flash").show();
                            $("img#full_image").hide();
                            $("#test").fadeOut("slow");

                        }); 
                        return false;

                    });

                });
                </script>
                </body>
                </html>
```

this basically has some thumbs, and when you click it it is loaded as a main image. There is also a thumb which loads a swf file, when clicked. Also I have a fade in / fade out effect when the main image / swf is loaded. This works in chrome and firefox, but when I try in IE, the div which is loaded by the jquery pushes the content downward. Can anyone help to debug this?

Thanks

Comment: Your overlay (div or image) need to be absolute/fixed positioned. The image tag you show onclick isn't. Does your test div work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a doctype, so your page is using [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

Add as the very first line this, the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I didn't actually test to see if this fixes your problem, but the chances are good.

For instance, you're using `position: fixed` which does not work in Quirks Mode in IE.

Comment: OMG!!! I never knew this. lol.

Thanks definitely learn something new everyday!!!!

This fixed the problem.